# MPMoviePlayerController Progress Indicator for video download

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to show a video from the internet. When you use the default controls you see the progress of the video download. I am creating my own custom controls and would like to have an indicator of the download progress.

Is there a MPMoviePlayerController property I can access that will give me this progress? If so I can not see it documented. If not, has anyone got a nice workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the property `playableDuration` of `MPMoviePlayerController`.

From the [`MPMoviePlayerController` Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/playableDuration):

---

`playableDuration`

The amount of currently playable content. (read-only)

`@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval playableDuration`

**Discussion**

For progressively downloaded network content, this property reflects the amount of content that can be played now.

**Availability**

Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Declared In
`MPMoviePlayerController.h`